# How to use custom ResourceManager in the auto-generated resource designer class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create my own `ResourceManager` that would override `GetString` method.

Then I want the resources designer to use my own `ResourceManager` inside the generated `<ResourceName>.Designer.cs` file.

I don't know where I can register my custom ResourceManager, so it is used by the resource designer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!